# assembly instruction length of 32-bit program

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, machine-code

i build a simple program and use file command to check program is 32-bit format.
in turn, i use objdump to disassemble program and found some assembly instruction length larger than 4-byte.

i expect the program is 32-bit format. therefore, those assembly instruction length should not bigger than 4-byte.
obviously, i am wrong. could you please tell me why it has 6-byte or 7-byte assembly instruction? thanks.

```
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=09aa196a671a6e169f09984360133ad9488f7e53, not stripped
```

```
$ objdump -d a.out
a.out:     file format elf32-i386

Disassembly of section .init:

 080482a8 <_init>:
 80482a8:       53                      push   %ebx
 80482a9:       83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 80482ac:       e8 8f 00 00 00          call   8048340 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
 80482b1:       81 c3 4f 1d 00 00       add    $0x1d4f,%ebx
 80482b7:       8b 83 fc ff ff ff       mov    -0x4(%ebx),%eax
 80482bd:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 80482bf:       74 05                   je     80482c6 <_init+0x1e>
 80482c1:       e8 3a 00 00 00          call   8048300 <__libc_start_main@plt+0x10>
 80482c6:       83 c4 08                add    $0x8,%esp
 80482c9:       5b                      pop    %ebx
 80482ca:       c3                      ret
```

Comment: 32 bit doesn't mean instructions are 32 bit. x86 has variable instruction length in all modes. The general purpose registers and the address space is 32 bit.

Comment: x86 instructions can be anywhere from 1 to 15 bytes regardless of operation mode.

Comment: Though about RISC V, and though about 64-bit computers, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56874990/471129) is relevant to what a 32-bit computer means, which is to say a 32- or 64-bit computer is about the size of the address space and the ability to easily manipulate 32- or 64-bit pointers (respectively), to read/write them from memory, to add & subtract them -- it is not about instruction size.

Answer (score 4):

Why?  One obvious reason is so a single instruction can *include* a 32-bit immediate, like `mov $address, %register`.  And so a `call rel32` can reach any 32-bit address from the current address.

These instructions need room for an opcode (1 byte) and sometimes a ModR/M byte to specify which register(s) / memory are operands.

If an instruction was limited to 4 bytes, it would take multiple instructions to put a static address into a register, and you couldn't use one as a memory-direct addressing mode.  RISC ISAs typically need 2 instructions to construct arbitrary 32-bit constants (including addresses) in register, like MIPS `lui $t0, high_half` / `ori $t0, $t0, low_half`

---

**x86 is variable-length CISC; common instructions are short, but longer instructions are possible instead of forcing you to construct an address or constant in a register with a separate instruction.**

e.g. you can do `movl $123456, some_static_variable` and get an instruction encoding with these components:

```
mov_opcode (1B)   Mod/RM (1B)    disp32 absolute address (4B)    imm32=123456 (4B)
```

for a total of 10 bytes, including two 4-byte values.  (In Intel's instruction-set reference manual (vol.2 of the x86 SDM), this is the [`mov r/m32, imm32` form of MOV](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov), with a `[disp32]` addressing mode.)

You could make it longer with prefixes, for example an `fs:` segment override prefix for thread-local storage.  And/or the addressing mode could include a scaled-index register, like `movl $123456, array(,%ecx,4)`, so a SIB (scale/index/base) byte would be needed after the ModRM to encode the addressing mode.

Instead of `mov`, we could have used `add`, and then we could also have used a `lock` prefix to make it an atomic read-modify write.

The hard limit on instruction length is 15 bytes.  If decoding doesn't find the end of an instruction by then, a `#UD` illegal instruction exception is raised.  (A Linux kernel will deliver a SIGILL to the offending process.)

(Fun fact: original 8086 had no limit, and would happily keep looping trying to decode a whole 64k segment full of `rep` prefixes)

Answer (score 3):

The instruction length is not limited to 32 bits. From [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) Wikipedia page:

> The x86 architecture is a variable instruction length, primarily
>   "CISC" design.

and

> Encoding  Variable (1 to 15 bytes)

And from [Intel® 64 and IA-32 architectures software developer’s manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf#page=3919):

> The Intel386 processor  sets a limit of 15 bytes on instruction length.