# How much should I add when using "jal" in RISC-V and 1 word is 8-byte

Tags: assembly, riscv

How much should I add when using "jal" in RISC-V and 1 word is 8-byte?

`jal x10 foo //x10 has O`

As I know, "jal" instruction place foo address in PC(program counter, x2) so procedure can jump to foo, and in parallel, place (PC + 4) value in x10 (in this code) as return address to excute next procedure after return.

What I'm curious about is, using RISC-V ISA and 1 word is 8-byte, which number should I add, 4 or 8?

Likeas, when 1 word is 8-byte, how should I set offset?

For example,

f = g + A[8] (f, g are placed in x5, x6, respectively)

(base address of A[] is placed in x10)

`add x5, x6, 64(x10)` is it right?

I assume it's correct because index * word = 8 * 8(byte) = 64

I studied in 1 word = 4-byte architecture so all I know is

A[8] (base address is placed in x10) is same as 2(x10) <- True.

If in 1 word = 8-byte architecture,

and if A[8] is same as 1(x10), it means 1 word is automatically considered as 8-byte, then
why there exists ld (load doubleword) instruction? I guess it's false.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, but instructions are 4 bytes hence the `PC + 4` which is quite clear. I don't understand what you are trying to do with the `add`.

Comment: Ah add was just another example, but now I think 4 in (PC + 4) and offset are different.

What I confuse is if when I use 4-byte architecture and 8-byte architecture, offset value and 4 in PC + 4 changes or not, because 1 word is changed .

Comment: It does not change because instructions are still 4 bytes even in riscv64.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!! I searched it for hours but I couldn't find answer.

Comment: `words` are data, so they don't affect instruction sizes.  They do affect register sizes, but since they don't affect instruction sizes, then the PC is simply wider, but the `jal` is the same size, so the same value is added.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807066/riscv32-vs-riscv64/62819417#62819417

Comment: Thanks, I read that page, I'm now understand 32-bit and 64-bit differ in register size, not instruction size.
ahhhhh I get it. even though using 64-bit architecture, A[8] is still 32(x10)..
Thanks again. It became clear.

Comment: Yeah, the 64-bit processor has one more naturally supported data size, though a language like C determines sizes of scalars and/or array elements, so a 32-bit machine can use 64-bit scalars (or array elements) just needs more instructions for add/mult etc.., since that 64-bit size isn't as well supported on those processors.